# CS50 Speller Valgrind and misspelled words

Tags: c, memory, valgrind, cs50

Hello everyone so I am doing Harvard's CS50 and I stumbled across a pretty interesting problem that I haven't been able to fix. The idea of the program is to check from a huge list of words which ones are misspelled and at the end of it free the memory.
These are the errors I haven't been able to correct.

```
:) dictionary.c, dictionary.h, and Makefile exist
:) speller compiles
:( handles most basic words properly
    expected "MISSPELLED WOR...", not "MISSPELLED WOR..."
:) handles min length (1-char) words
:) handles max length (45-char) words
:) handles words with apostrophes properly
:) spell-checking is case-insensitive
:) handles substrings properly
```

These are the specific errors,

```
running ./speller basic/dict basic/text...
checking for output "MISSPELLED WORDS\n\n\nWORDS MISSPELLED: 0\nWORDS IN DICTIONARY: 8\nWORDS IN TEXT: 9\n"...

Expected Output:
MISSPELLED WORDS


WORDS MISSPELLED:     0
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  8
WORDS IN TEXT:        9
Actual Output:
MISSPELLED WORDS

over

WORDS MISSPELLED:     1
WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  8
WORDS IN TEXT:        9
```

for some odd reason the word that seems to be misspelled is actually spelled correctly. 
The other error is as follows:

```
valgrind tests failed; rerun with --log for more information.
Log
running valgrind --show-leak-kinds=all --xml=yes --xml-file=/tmp/tmpicmfiai5 -- ./speller substring/dict substring/text...
checking for output "MISSPELLED WORDS\n\nca\ncats\ncaterpill\ncaterpillars\n\nWORDS MISSPELLED: 4\nWORDS IN DICTIONARY: 2\nWORDS IN TEXT: 6\n"...
checking that program exited with status 0...
checking for valgrind errors...
112 bytes in 2 blocks are still reachable in defeat record 1 of 2: (file: dictionary.c, line: 76)
336 bytes in 6 blocks are definitely lost in defeat record 2 of 2: (file: dictionary.c, line: 31)
```

Now i will add my entire code:

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dictionary.h"


// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;


// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 27;
int word_count;
char dictionary_word[LENGTH + 1];
// Hash table
node *table[N];

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    node *cursor = malloc(sizeof(node));
    int word_pos = hash(word);
    cursor = table[word_pos];

    while (cursor != NULL)
    {
        if(strcasecmp (cursor->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    int index = 0 ;
    for(int i = 0 ; word[i] != '\0' ; i++)
    {
        index += tolower(word[i]) ;
    }
    return index % N ;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // open the file
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    // check if file is null
    if (!file)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "File does not exist.\n");
        return false;
    }

    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    word_count = 0;

    while(fscanf(file, "%s", dictionary_word) != EOF)
    {
        // allocate memory for the new node
        node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (new_node == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }

        strcpy(new_node->word, dictionary_word);
        int hashed = hash(dictionary_word);

        if(table[hashed] == NULL)
        {
            table[hashed] = new_node;
            new_node->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            new_node->next = table[hashed];
            table[hashed] = new_node->next;
        }
        word_count++;
    }

    fclose(file);
    return true;
}


// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    //just return the word count, easy piesey.
    return word_count;
}


// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node *cursor = NULL;
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            node *tmp = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->next;
            free(tmp);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Thank you very much, if any more info is needed i will provided as soon as i see the message. Thx.

Comment: dictionary.h would be nice as well.

Comment: You malloc in check, but don't add it to any list - heck you throw it away and just assign table over it.  That is not right.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan thanks for the comment, how would i fix? and sorry

Comment: "Now i will add my entire code:" -->  Post `LENGTH` definition.  Better yet [mcve]

Comment: `const unsigned int N = 27; ... node *table[N];` is not valid C.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica well, thats no helpful. Any idea on HOW to fix the errors that I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code with `small lalaland.txt`,  there are two memory blocks allocated at `dictionary.c::76` that are not freed before exiting.  The following is the error message. You can use this [link](https://cee.studio/?bucket=200604-dhM&name=speller) to reproduce it.   For all the memory blocks returned by `malloc`, you need to call `free` once.   You can use `printf` to find out which memory blocks are not freed. It's better to use a small dictionary and small text input to do this debugging.

```
 Memory access warning: memory spaces are not freed; continue execution.
 # 2 memory spaces are allocated at
 #    file:/dictionary.c::76, 26
 # total 104 bytes
 #
```

Comment: so I would have to free those malloc before the unload function?

Comment: you need to free all of them in `unload` function.

Comment: first of all, thanks for the link. I added free(cursor) and free(new_node) and the same error popped up. as a matter of fact when I tried adding the free(new_node) in the unload function I had an undeclared identifier error. by i literally added those lines like that.